# How do I ignore ._ prefixed files from Jest's testRegex check?

Tags: javascript, regex, jestjs

I'm working within a Vagrant environment, which appears to leave some cached/metadata versions of files around, including tests.

So Jest will run both:

`__tests__/myTest.spec.js
__tests__/._myTest.spec.js`

Turns out Jest offers a testRegex matcher for your package.json: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testregex-string

The default testRegex is `(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.jsx?$`

How can I make it ignore files starting with `_.` ?

Comment: Add a negative lookahead after `^`, `^(?!_).*` or `^(?!_(?!_))` if you need to ignore files with only one `_`. Note you must write a consuming pattern that matches the whole string then.

Comment: They must have some strange escaping as that regex does not look correct (double escape to the dot)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've tried adding a negative lookeahead, but can't seem to figure it out. How would that work within: `/__tests__\/.*|(\\.|\/)(test|spec)` ?